# How to reflesh $scope in Angular in AJAX reponse?

Tags: angularjs

I have AJAX response inside that is deleted object:

```
request.success(function (data) {
    delete $scope.notifications.system[key];
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

I have HTML code with block, that would be appear by condition:

```
<span ng-show="notifications.system.length == 0" ng-cloak>
DELETED
</span>
```

So, I tried to use `$scope.$apply();` in response at once after removing object. But I have got error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
```

How I can reload template when `notifications.system.length` is equal zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use delete on arrays it doesn't change the length of the array instead it replaces the element in the array with undefined. So your ng-show never changes because the length of the array isn't changing. Use splice instead and the array will shorten and your $scope should update at you expect.

```
$scope.notifications.system.splice($scope.notifications.system.indexOf(key), 1);
```

you shouldn't need $scope.$apply() for something like this.

Comment: I get error:  `$scope.notifications.system.indexOf is not a function`

Comment: It is object, not array

Comment: Ok there's part of your problem. You can't use '.length' on objects.

Comment: Wait please, I will check it and share

Comment: You can try Object.keys($scope.notifications.system).length but I'm not sure if angular will evaluate it in the ng-show. Also Object.Keys isn't available in some browsers, notably IE9 and below

Comment: Can I use `Object.keys($scope.notifications.system).length` in template HTML for `ng-repeat`?

Comment: That's what I meant when I said 'I'm not sure if angular will evaluate it in the ng-show'. I don't know if it'll work in the HTML. You'll have to try and see if it works since I can't test it right now. My guess is that is won't. But you should be able to bind a variable into the $scope to use for the count and update it with Object.Keys(...).length after deleting the property.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to use the $scope.$apply() you should wrap everything in a $timeout and call it like this.

```
request.success(function(resp){
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            //do stuff here to the scope.
        });
    });
});
```

Passing in a function reference to `$apply` will cause it to execute that function then `$digest`.  Seems a bit strange I know, but the reason for this is that AngularJS typically calls `$digest` in response to user interaction, not necessarily to events like `$http.success`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the managing of your errors differently.
Instead of adding directly to an object you could add the error objects to an array.
Deleting can then be done with the following code:

```
$scope.removeError = function (errorName) {
    angular.forEach($scope.notifications, function (error, index) {
        if (error.hasOwnProperty(errorName)) $scope.notifications.pop(index);
    });
};
```

Have a look at the demo below and here at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/kmnfwo3a/2/).

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('mainController', MainController);

function MainController($http, $scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.notifications = [{
        errorImg: 'failed to load image',
    }//, 
    /*{ // other errors
        //errorJS: 'failed to load js'
    }*/];

    $scope.removeError = function (errorName) {
        angular.forEach($scope.notifications, function (error, index) {
            //console.log(index, error.hasOwnProperty(errorName), $scope.notifications);
            if (error.hasOwnProperty(errorName)) $scope.notifications.pop(index);
            //console.log(index, error.hasOwnProperty(errorName), $scope.notifications);
        });
    };
    $scope.clear = function () {
        $http.jsonp('http://www.mocky.io/v2/556f7ba53db19a8f05f1e555?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
            .success(function (response) {
            //dummy request
            //console.log(response, $scope.notifications);

            //delete $scope.notifications['errorImg'];
            $scope.removeError('errorImg');
        }) //.bind(this))
    }
}

MainController.$inject = ['$http', '$scope', '$timeout'];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='mainController as main'> <pre>{{notifications |json}}</pre>

    <!--<button ng-click="main.show()">Show data</button>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="info in main.data">{{info.test}}</li>
    </ul>-->
    <button ng-click="clear()">clear error</button>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in dummy">{{i}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-show="notifications.length == 0">deleted</div>
</div>
```